# Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials on local machine

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I have created a `credentials.txt` at `~/.aws/credentials.txt`
I have added the credentials at `~/.aws/credentials.txt` as

```
[bogdan-ses-user]
aws_access_key_id = ***
aws_secret_access_key = ***
```

**Local Node JS server**

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

// import entire SDK
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');



    var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'bogdan-ses-user'});
    AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
    console.log(credentials);



    AWS.config.getCredentials(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("err comes hereeee");
            console.log(err.stack);
        }else{

            console.log('Access key: ', AWS.config.getCredentials.accessKeyId);
        }
    });

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('server has started');

});
```

**Console Print out ERROR***

> (base) bogdanmac:ProjectDemo iliebogdanbarbulescu$ node app.js
> SharedIniFileCredentials {   expired: false,   expireTime: null,
> refreshCallbacks: [],   accessKeyId: undefined,   sessionToken:
> undefined,   filename: undefined,   profile: 'bogdan-ses-user',
> disableAssumeRole: false,   preferStaticCredentials: false,
> tokenCodeFn: null,   httpOptions: null } err comes hereeee
> CredentialsError: Could not load credentials from
> SharedIniFileCredentials
> at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
> at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
> at Object.readFileSync (/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/Documents/ProjectDemo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:95:26)
> at IniLoader.parseFile (/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/Documents/ProjectDemo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:6:47)
> at IniLoader.loadFrom (/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/Documents/ProjectDemo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:56:30)
> at Object.getProfilesFromSharedConfig (/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/Documents/ProjectDemo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:965:39)
> at SharedIniFileCredentials.load (/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/Documents/ProjectDemo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials/shared_ini_file_credentials.js:96:31)
> at SharedIniFileCredentials.coalesceRefresh (/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/Documents/ProjectDemo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:205:12)
> at SharedIniFileCredentials.refresh (/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/Documents/ProjectDemo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials/shared_ini_file_credentials.js:168:10)
> at SharedIniFileCredentials.get (/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/Documents/ProjectDemo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:122:12)
> server has started successful connection done

Comment: You just shared your access key and secret access key on the internet, you should revoke them asap

Comment: They are dummy keys

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SharedIniFileCredentials.html) says:

> **filename** (String) — default: '~/.aws/credentials' or defined by AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE process env var — the filename to use when loading credentials.

So you can either:

- Rename your file `~/.aws/credentials.txt` to `~/.aws/credentials`
- Set the environment variable `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=~/.aws/credentials`
- Use the `filename` option:

```js
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({filename: '~/.aws/credentials.txt', profile: 'bogdan-ses-user'});
```

Comment: I still get the same error ```CredentialsError: Could not load credentials from SharedIniFileCredentials```. What I did?: renamed the file to ```~/.aws/credentials``` , run in terminal ```export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=~/.aws/credentials```, https://imgur.com/aPo6ked . Also see https://imgur.com/M9du1Ij

Comment: The environment variable seems to be set too https://imgur.com/D3sqfal ```AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/Users/iliebogdanbarbulescu/.aws/credentials
_CE_M=```

Comment: It doesn't work, I've been all over it for the past 4 hours..

Comment: You can't rename your file `credentials` and also use `filename: credentials.txt` you have to chose one or another. `filename` must be the actual name of your file.